# Space Engineers Automatic Jump Drive

Tags: space-engineers

From my understanding, there is no way to do an auto jump with the jump drive. Has anyone figured out a way to use vanilla Space Engineers to achieve this task?

My reasoning for this is in case an enemy approaches the ship while I'm not present, sensors would detect it then jump to a designated location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You cannot.](https://github.com/malware-dev/MDK-SE/wiki/List-Of-Terminal-Properties-and-Actions#imyjumpdrive).
The reference linked have a list of everything programmable with command blocks.

Currently, you can do the following with the Jump Drive block via scripts:

- Change the jump distance (Increase or decrease);
- Toggle the block (Either on, off or toggle (on->off or off->on));
- Recharge the block (Either on, off or toggle (on->off or off->on)); and
- Show on hud (Either on, off or toggle (on->off or off->on))

You could alternatively use a Sound Block to alert you that something is amiss, however this would not work if you are far from the computer, and it would require you to go to it and click a button.

Comment: As of 2022 you can now use the custom turret controller block to target enemy grids up to 800m away, and setup an action/ timer block to go off then